# Error en ciclo For, me saca sin previo aviso

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Actualmente tengo un arreglo de imágenes de PictureBox y quiero recorrerlo para aplicarles una imagen a las imágenes que están después de este mes, cada imagen representa un mes y ya hice el ciclo `for`:

Ciclo `for`:

```
for (int MesE = Convert.ToInt16(Mes); Convert.ToInt16(Mes) <= pics.Length;MesE++)
{
    pics[MesE].Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\..\Imagenes\NoAplica.png");
    pics[MesE].Enabled = false;
}
```

Todo va bien excepto por el defecto de que cuando hago el *debuegeo* de mi aplicación y llega a la línea `pics[MesE].Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\..\Imagenes\NoAplica.png");` se cicla, pero no se cicla dentro del ciclo `for` sino que me saca al siguiente método:

```
this.Hide();
Modal_General general = new Modal_General();
general.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
general.Show();
```

Y de ahí se va a otro método que es donde hace un bucle infinito y si le doy <kbd>F5</kbd> se acaba el bucle pero no me hace la acción del bucle `for` que está arriba.

Código donde se hace el bucle:

```
private void horaActual(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String tiempo = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    lblTiempo.Text = "Hora Actual: " + tiempo;
}
```

Yo sé que está todo bien raro, no sé a qué se deba esto, talvés hice algo mal.

Comment: Usualmente, cuando el código actúa de una forma que nos parece misterioso, el problema está donde menos lo esperamos, por lo que probablemente no has incluído la parte problemática. Lo idea es que vayas depurando y simplificando hasta que puedas llegar a un [mcve] que puedes incluir en la pregunta.

Comment: En la línea: `for (int MesE = Convert.ToInt16(Mes); Convert.ToInt16(Mes) <= pics.Length;MesE++)`, Debería ser: `for (int MesE = Convert.ToInt16(Mes); MesE <= pics.Length;MesE++)`, debido a que en ningún momento estás evaluando para terminar el bucle.

Comment: Más allá del error que te indica Davlio, quizás lo que te sucede es que hay varios threads simultáneos, como suele suceder con Windows Forms. Pon un breakpoint dentro del `for`, presiona F5 y debería seguir allí. Recuerda que con tu código actual ese bucle es infinito, ya que en la condición nunca comparas contra `MesE`.

Comment: @Andrew ya puse el breakpoint dentro del ciclo for pero cuando le doy F5 me saca y se ejecuta el programa, se supone que deberia ejecutarse varias veces con F5 antes de que me saque del ciclo, sabes a que se deba esa posible reaccion o como bloquear los threads de windosforms en caso de que ese sea el error, hay problema si el for esta dentro del metodo del load de mi formulario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontre el problema y no se a que se deba la verdad, pero el ciclo for lo puse dentro de mi metodo de cargar y pues por algo una razon si lo ponia en el constructor todo funcionaba de manera correcta.

Metodo donde estaba el problema:

```
 private void Modal_General_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Mi solucion fue cambiar mi codigo al constructor de mi formulario.

Comment: Lo que pongas en el constructor se ejecutará cuando hagas `new Modal_General()`, lo que pongas en _Load se ejecutará cuando hagas `.Show()`.

Comment: @Andrew Gracias, eso explica lo del bucle y lo de que entrara a otro metodo

Comment: Igual de todas formas nunca debería sacarte del bucle a no ser que la condición ya no se cumpla o algo mate el thread (hilo), cosa que normalmente no debería suceder. Con la condición corregida te sigue sucediendo?

Comment: @Andrew no, ya funcion de manera correcta.